# Investigating wireless issues Windows vs. Linux same access point

Tags: wireless-networking, wireless-access-point

I have my computer set to dual boot with Windows and Linux. Under Windows I can connect and use the wifi with no problems. If I boot up into Linux in the exact same spot in the same room. My signal is lower quality and actually disconnects me after 2-5 minutes. It reauthenticates within another 10-20 seconds usually but this is a general pain in the butt. The only thing I have come up with so far is that maybe my DHCP lease is being set too low under the Linux machine and its expiring all the time. But I've also noticed the same issues with wifi on my ipod touch. What kinds of things could i look for?

Answer (score 0):

DHCP lease is handled by the router, it doesn't care which operating system you're using, it will lease IPs the same regardless. It is possible there is an issue with the wireless driver that your linux install is using. Try to update the drivers and see if it continues. As far as the ipod touch goes, I really don't know enough about those to troubleshoot, but if you are seeing the exact same symptoms on multiple devices, then there could be something going on with the router, or something between the router and those two devices for some reason. You may need to try additional wireless devices for further testing.

Answer (score 0):

Yes as MaQleod says update your linux distribution or try resetting your connection. (See also the connection/disconnection logs?)
For the iPod touch problem, in fact it does this by design to avoid killing your battery (I mean in standby mode, so when you unlock it the wifi signal takes like 10 seconds to appear - if it does that while you're using it there might be a problem with your access point)